# CLIPS eval stops working if fact does not exist

Tags: c++, clips

I am using the `CLIPS` API `EnvEval` in order to find a fact given its relation:

```
auto expression = "(find-all-facts ((?f system)) TRUE)";

DATA_OBJECT outputValue;

auto res = EnvEval(pEnvironment, expression, &outputValue);
return res;
```

But my problem is that if I try to find a fact which does not exist in the current list of facts, the `EnvEval` will always return FALSE even for facts which do exist, for each single new call.

Why this behavior and what am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Olaf CLIPS API are completely written in C... I am not spamming tags!

Comment: The code above is definitively not C. You because you use a C library does not justify the C tag. Otherwise every question would be C, because all libs end at some C code.

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce the behavior based on the code fragments you've provided.

Answer (score 1):

Your source code is very partial and I do not 
know if I understand the situation correctly.

But, anyway, here's a working quick hack, according to
your problem, that might help.

PS: CLIPS is very stable, well documented and updated (thanks to Gary).

(compiled with clang and gcc under linux)

file: sample.clp

```
(deffacts dummy-example ""
  (not-important blá)
  (dummy foo)
  (useless bar)
  (my-system aaa)
  (just-noise bbb)
  (my-system bbb)
  (my-system ccc))
```

C code

```
#include "clips.h"

int main(/* int argc, char *argv[] */)
{
  void *theEnv;
  char *expression;
  DATA_OBJECT outputValue;
  char *result;

  void *multifieldPtr, *factPtr;
  long end, i;

  theEnv = CreateEnvironment();

  EnvLoad(theEnv, "sample.clp");
  EnvReset(theEnv);
  EnvRun(theEnv, -1);

  expression = strdup("(find-all-facts ((?f my-system)) TRUE)");

  if (!EnvEval(theEnv, expression, &outputValue)) {
    EnvPrintRouter(theEnv, WPROMPT,
                   "NOT successfully evaluated\n");
  } else {

    /* Print the result of find-all-facts field by field */
    if (GetType(outputValue) == MULTIFIELD) {

      end = GetDOEnd(outputValue);
      multifieldPtr = GetValue(outputValue);
      EnvPrintRouter(theEnv,WPROMPT,"( ");
      for (i = GetDOBegin(outputValue); i <= end; i++){
          if (GetMFType(multifieldPtr,i) == FACT_ADDRESS){
            factPtr = GetMFValue(multifieldPtr,i);
            asprintf(&result,"<Fact-%lld> ",
                     EnvFactIndex(theEnv, factPtr));
            EnvPrintRouter(theEnv,WPROMPT,result);
          }

      }
      EnvPrintRouter(theEnv,WPROMPT,")\n");
    } else {
      EnvPrintRouter(theEnv,WPROMPT,"Not a multifield!");
    }

  }

  return(0);
}
```

When you compile and run you get

```
( <Fact-4> <Fact-6> <Fact-7> )
```